# Xamarin Android app crashes on Galaxy Note 8

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My **Xamarin Forms Android** app **(Release mode)** crashes on Galaxy Note 8 **(Oreo 8.0)**. It shows the splash and dies immediately. Following is the crash log I received on console dashboard. But I'm unable to find the cause of this. It dies before AppCenter crash reporting kicks in. So this is the only log I got. Any idea what could be wrong here?

- Build: **Release**
- Works on other Oreo 8.0 and 7.1 devices
- Min SDK: **21**
- Target SDK: **26**
- Linker: Link SDK assemblies
- Multi dex **ON**
- Max heap **1G**
- Supports all CPU architectures

***_________***

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x00034] in <99988d4ab8d144898ef5bc7586876d75>:0 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0000a] in <99988d4ab8d144898ef5bc7586876d75>:0
    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00018] in <99988d4ab8d144898ef5bc7586876d75>:0
    at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <88e8d1026f2645cab4d71803e1b2caba>:0
    at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.268905bf-8ee6-4d7b-ac7e-88443c1482d9(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
      at md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
      at md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PlatformRenderer.onLayout (PlatformRenderer.java:55)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1080)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1791)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1635)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1544)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:944)
      at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20841)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6401)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2911)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2598)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1742)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7763)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6940)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your XAML view.  If the splash screen runs, then it must be the first real page has the problem.  I would try putting try/catch around the constructor of that page.

Comment: Usually with those kinds of odd crashes, there is something else going on. Is there an inner exception?Google sign-on for example can give a similar crash: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54422  Can you post the contents of your `OnCreate()`  ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your bin and obj folders in the Android project directory, then doing a clean and solution rebuild? I've solved similar errors just with this, and it's usually my goto troubleshooting step for errors around the build/deploy process

Answer (score 0):

I believe the suggestion from Bejasc of cleaning and deleting the obj and bin directories and creating a new release will resolve your problem.  I had the same crashes with releases running on Samsung Galaxy Note 8 Devices - on both Nougat and Oreo.  Bejasc's suggestion solved them.